# Unable to create a JWT token with ES256

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

I'm unable to create a token with ES256 to call device_check api in apple documentation.

I'm using ruby-2.2.3

```
jwt_token = JWT.encode({iss: team_id, iat: Time.now.to_i}, ec_key, 'ES256', {kid: key_id})
```

But I'm getting this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `group' for #<String:0x007..>
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/jwt-1.5.1/lib/jwt.rb:49:in `sign_ecdsa'
```

But this works fine with another encryption say HS256

Can someone please help me with creating this token with ES256

Comment: `ec_key` should be an instance of [`OpenSSL::PKey::EC`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/EC.html), not a string (the former responds to [`group`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/EC.html#method-i-group), the latter does not)

Comment: I tried to create ec_key like this : OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(private_key_string), but I'm getting this error - OpenSSL::PKey::ECError: unknown curve name (private_key_string)